# Vue - how to update a value in the view periodically with filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm just trying to make countdown timer with vue, but the view don't get updated.
My app.js and index.html:

```js
var nowDate = new Date;
var nextNewYearsEve = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), 11, 31, 23, 59, 59, 59);
var timeLeftToNewYearsEve = nextNewYearsEve - nowDate;
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  timeLeftToNewYearsEve: timeLeftToNewYearsEve
 },
 filters: {
  date: function (val) {

   var timeLeftMonth = new Date(val).getMonth();
   var timeLeftDay = new Date(val).getDay();
   var timeLeftHour = new Date(val).getHours();
   var timeLeftMinutes = new Date(val).getMinutes();
   var timeLeftSeconds = new Date(val).getSeconds();

   return timeLeftMonth + ' hónap  ' + timeLeftDay + ' nap  ' + timeLeftHour + ' óra  ' + timeLeftMinutes + ' perc  ' + timeLeftSeconds + ' és másodperc';
  }
 },
 methods: {
  update: function () {
   setInterval(function () {
    timeLeftToNewYearsEve = nextNewYearsEve - new Date();
    console.log(timeLeftToNewYearsEve);
   }, 1000);
  }
 }
});

app.update();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">
  {{timeLeftToNewYearsEve | date}}
 </div>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
 <script src="resource/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i missing, why don't get updated the value in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the value in Vue using `this`.

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.timeLeftToNewYearsEve = nextNewYearsEve - new Date();
  console.log(timeLeftToNewYearsEve);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Still not working with 'this' :( What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you change to use the arrow function?

Comment: Wow, thanks, with arrow function it is working. As i guess, arrow function handles 'this' different?

Comment: @aboutus Yes it does.